# How to pop up new window with tweet button

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, twitter, tweets

I have many custom tweet buttons on my page that I am dynamically generating using this line of PHP executed in a loop:

```
echo "<li><a href=\"https://twitter.com/share?text=Check%20out%20{$items[$i]['name']}%20at%20completeset.us/item/{$items[$i]['item_id']}&url=&via=cmpltst\"  class=\"twitter\">T</a></li>";
```

This works perfectly fine, however, this executes in the same tab and navigates me away from the page it was called from. I would like to open the share dialog in a new window, but my Javascript background is limited to form validation and a few Jquery Ajax calls, so I have no idea how to go about doing this. How could I pop up the dialog in a new window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have an on click Javascript function for your anchor tag anbd in that function use window.open() by passing your URL toopen it in new window.hope this works

Comment: That's basically exactly what I ended up doing based on this link: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html

Answer (score 21):

this worked me fine

```
<a target=_blank href=\"https://twitter.com/share?text=Check%20out%20{$items[$i]['name']}%20at%20completeset.us/item/{$items[$i]['item_id']}&url=&via=cmpltst\"  class=\"twitter\  onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');return false;" >T</a>
```

add onclick as

```
 onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href, '', 'menubar=no,
             toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');return false;"
```

Comment: You should not use `javascript:` in the `onclick` attribute, as this attribute is meant to JavaScript only. The `javascript:` should be used when inserting JavaScript code in `href` attribute, ie. `href="javascript:window.open[..]"`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the "target=_blank" to your a href:

```
echo "<li><a target=_blank href=\"https://twitter.com/share?text=Check%20out%20{$items[$i]['name']}%20at%20completeset.us/item/{$items[$i]['item_id']}&url=&via=cmpltst\"  class=\"twitter\">T</a></li>";
```

Comment: That pops it up in a new tab, so at least the user doesn't lose their place. I was hoping for a separate popup window though.